# Replace Index values with matched values in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

df1:

```
   Index   ColA  
     a      10   
     b       9   
     c      12   
     d      13
```

df2:

```
   Index  Letter  Names    
     0      d     Waylon    
     1      a     Marcus 
     2      z     Eddie 
     3      q     Justine 
     4      c     Angela 
     5      b     Joanna
```

I want to make to replace the index values in df1 with the corresponding values in df2, so the result would look like:

df1:

```
   Index   ColA  
   Marcus   10   
   Joanna    9   
   Angela   12   
   Waylon   13
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `rename` by `dictionary` created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
df1 = df1.rename(index=df1.set_index('Letter')['Names'].to_dict())
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael, thanks for your swift response. I tried this, but keep getting the following error: 'Series' object is not callable.
I might be because the column you called Index, is the actual index of the column..Do you know how to solve this?